# Following another object that is rotating

Tags: c++, matrix, rotation, directx, directx-11

I have three objects: `marshal`, `sergeant`, `soldier`. All of them are of `Human` type:

```
class Human{
public: //just to make question less complicated,
//let's assume all members are public
   DirectX::XMFLOAT3 position; //pivot point
   DirectX::XMFLOAT3 rotation;

   Human * follow;
   std::vector<Human *> followers;
   DirectX::XMFLOAT3 distanceToFollow;

   ...
   void render(){
      ...
      DirectX::XMMATRIX objectWorldMatrix = DirectX::XMMatrixIdentity();
      DirectX::XMMATRIX rotationMatrix = 
         DirectX::XMMatrixRotationX(rotation.x) * 
         DirectX::XMMatrixRotationY(rotation.y) * 
         DirectX::XMMatrixRotationZ(rotation.z)
      );
      ...
      DirectX::XMMATRIX translationMatrix = DirectX::XMMatrixTranslation(position.x, position.y, position.z);
      objectWorldMatrix =  scaleMatrix * rotationMatrix * translationMatrix;
      ...
   }

   void follow(Human * h){
       follow = h;
       h.followers.push_back(this);
       distanceToFollow = h.position - position;
   }
};
```

The relation between them looks like that:

```
soldier.follow(sergeant);
sergeant.follow(marshal);
```

What I want now is to make `soldier` following `sergeant` and `sergeant` following the `marshal`. So when, for instance, **`marshal` moves, everybody moves and keep their distances (as well as relative angles) to each other** (the "visualization" is 2D for simplify, but I am working with 3D models):

[image]

For position changes, that will do:

```
void Human::setPosition(XMFFLOAT3 newPosition){
    position = newPosition;
    for(auto &follower : followers){
        follower.setPosition(newPosition - follower.distanceToFollow);
        //keep the distance, soldier!
    }
}
```

But I cannot figure out, **how to make the same for rotation?.**

When `marshal` rotates, `sergeant` will change both its `position` and `rotation`.

I am after few failures. During my last try, when I rotated `marshal` by `[40, 0, 0]`, then `[0, 30, 0]`, then `[-40, 0, 0]` and `[0, -30, 0]`, `sergeant` ended in place different then before all those rotations (`marshal` backed to place as it should, with rotation `[0, 0, 0]` - the relative distance has been broken). Maybe it's because of order of calculations.

Anyway, I don't want to suggest the wrong way of solving the problem, so will just ask you: **how to write the** `Human::setRotation(XMFFLOAT3 newRotation)` **method?**

**Note:** There is no interpolations/animations for now (from one state to another), so I guess that quaternions won't be necessary.

---

**My attempt**

At first I did not want to post it. It's because I think it contains an mistakes and I do not want to suggest them to you (I though it easier to compare with right solution than to find the bug in the wrong one). But if you want to check my buggy code:

```
Human::setRotation(XMFFLOAT3 newRotation){
    XMFFLOAT3 oldRotation = rotation;
    rotation = newRotation;
    for(auto &follower : followers){
        follower.rotateAround(newRotation - oldRotation, rotationDiffrenceToFollowTarget, position);
        //keep the relative angle, soldier!
    }
}

Human::rotateAround(XMFFLOAT3 radians, XMFFLOAT3 origin){
    DirectX::XMMATRIX rotX = DirectX::XMMatrixRotationX(radians.x);
    DirectX::XMMATRIX rotY = DirectX::XMMatrixRotationY(radians.y);
    DirectX::XMMATRIX rotZ = DirectX::XMMatrixRotationZ(radians.z);

    DirectX::XMMATRIX worldM = rotX * rotY * rotZ;

    DirectX::XMFLOAT3 positionTemp = DirectX::XMFLOAT3(
        position.x - origin.x, position.y - origin.y, position.z - origin.z);
    DirectX::XMVECTOR pos = XMLoadFloat3(&positionTemp);
    pos = XMVector3Transform(pos, worldM);
    XMStoreFloat3(&positionTemp, pos);

    positionTemp.x = positionTemp.x + origin.x;
    positionTemp.y = positionTemp.y + origin.y;
    positionTemp.z = positionTemp.z + origin.z;

    setPosition(positionTemp); //so followers will get noticed
    rotation += radians;
}
```

And the `rotationDiffrenceToFollowTarget` is computed as:

```
Human::void follow(Human * h){
    follow = h;
    h.followers.push_back(this);
    distanceToFollow = h.position - position;
    rotationDiffrenceToFollowTarget = h.rotation - rotation;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't subtract a set of three rotation angles and expect sense because 3D rotations don't commute, and that pretty much wrecks your approach. Your three angles area not much use for anything - it's an all-in-one matrix you want to store.

The way to do this is to express each individual movement of the leader as a single matrix and apply exactly that matrix to the followers as well. For translations this matrix is just a translation, and for rotations it's a translation of the leader to the origin followed by a simple rotation that reflects the UI action that caused it, followed by the reverse translation. When I say "followed by" I mean "premultiplied by".

If that UI action is supposed to be character-centric, i.e. if turning left feels the same whichever way up you are, then you'll also have to unwind the current rotation before applying the change and re-apply it afterwards, but the translations are still outermost. Without this follow-the-leader feature that would boil down to simply post-multiplying the current matrix by the change, but for the follower, you'll apply the inverse of the leader's current matrix, then the change, then the old current matrix.

This doesn't work with your multi-stage following thing, so you'll have to express that as both followers following the one leader directly.

Another option is to find a matrix that transforms the leader's entire state onto the follower's and when the leader moves around you postmultiply his state by that matrix to get the follower's state. By "state" I mean position and orientation expressed as a single matrix. How do you find that matrix in the first place? If it's called M while L and F are the two states, then L.M=F so M=Inv(L).F

Is that specific enough? ;-)

Comment: That was just what I was doing before, with a help of rotation matrices. But it did not work (rotation around [a,0,0] was ok, then [0,b,0] also, but when I rotated back by [-a,0,0] and then [0,-b,0], the relative distance was different). And that's why I am asking you for example so I can find out where I made mistake (which I cannot see now). Also, note that it's 3D (and not 2D) problem (should be a bit analogical anyway).

Comment: So why don't you post the code that does what I suggested so that we can all try to spot the bug?

Comment: Because I don't want you to follow to code and make the same mistake (= I don't want to suggest you my error). But as you wish, I've published my code below the question.

Comment: Don't I do it? Firstly I decrease follower's position by the origin (boss position is an `origin`), then rotate (boss position is now the origin for rotation) and then increase follower's position by the origin. Strange thing is that works for rotation in one direction, but for composition like I described - not. Can you post the modified code of mine? Because I really don't see what should be changed here.

Comment: Please be more precise, because I really don't get it. I've posted the code - can you show me where I do sth wrong by posting the correction? I do multiply matrices in order etc. After rotating main object by (in that order): [a,0,0]->[0,b,0]->[-a,0,0]->[0,-b,0] main object DO returns to right place and the follower does NOT.

Comment: I think there's confusion between angles and angle differences when you recurse into setRotation. setRotation takes an absolute angle but you pass a difference to rotateAround and then pass that difference to the follower's setRotation

Comment: Once again, I am asking you for clarification. Can't you point the problem precisely (I guess the code or pseudo-code would be strongly recommended)? Don't take it as offend, but you seem to changing mind in every next comment by giving some different (and very generic) suggestions: firstly about "you translate back to origin", then "rotations don't commute" and now some "confusion" (I extended my question by additional code once more).

Comment: I deleted my comment about the origin cos I saw that you were indeed doing it like I suggested. I'm currently using my mobile so I can't write the code for you. But my comment about the angle differences is pretty precise already. As for the non-commuting rotations, I'm still trying to figure out how your code should behave. But the one about the angle differences looks like a clear bug to me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63283/discussion-between-adrian-may-and-polgraphic).